# Domain variants http https and Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console

Hopefully a quick question.
I've just set up and launched a site and with Google's webmaster tools search console thing, I go to add my site which is great.

But I've been looking around to try and find what site URLs I should add. Here, google have a page regarding this:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=en

On there it lists add the http and https sites separately.

I've set the config to redirect all requests to http, http + www and https to go to https://www.sitename if that makes sense.

The question is that in this case, should I add all 4 variants to google's webmaster tools or just the one that I'm using(https://www. version)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add all versions, but that is not necessarily.

Also, you can set up preferred domain for google: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the best idea is to enter ALL your domain variants, including https variants if you use SSL for this reason: if you get penalties against a variant of your domain and you haven't registered it *you will not see the warning messages in Google Search Console* (Google Webmaster Tools) and never know what is killing your traffic.